# Interpreting R results, are the data multivariate normal?

Tags: r, machine-learning, normal-distribution, clustering, model

I ran "mvn" using the "mclust" package in R using the following codes:

```
mvn("EEE", data[,18:22], prior = NULL, warn= NULL)
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to tell if the results are indicating "multivariate normal fit". The results are below:

```
$n
[1] 707

$d
[1] 5

$G
[1] 1

$parameters
    $parameters$pro
[1] 1

$parameters$mean
        [,1]
V18 2.993399
V19 3.775578
V20 3.790193
V21 2.652051
V22 3.235266

$parameters$variance
$parameters$variance$modelName
[1] "XXX"

$parameters$variance$d
[1] 5

$parameters$variance$G
[1] 1

$parameters$variance$Sigma
            V18          V19          V20          V21         V22
V18  1.11483935 -0.046114371  0.021088813  0.094512987 -0.03160755
V19 -0.04611437  0.604042865 -0.001037869  0.001748973  0.13845048
V20  0.02108881 -0.001037869  0.511536706  0.112759387 -0.17223313
V21  0.09451299  0.001748973  0.112759387  0.542454933 -0.13187494
V22 -0.03160755  0.138450479 -0.172233126 -0.131874937  0.81860855

$parameters$variance$cholSigma
        [,1]        [,2]          [,3]         [,4]        [,5]
[1,] 1.05586 -0.04367472  0.0199731239  0.089512842 -0.02993537
[2,] 0.00000  0.77597383 -0.0002133427  0.007292026  0.17673671
[3,] 0.00000  0.00000000 -0.7149389730 -0.155220369  0.24001701
[4,] 0.00000  0.00000000  0.0000000000  0.714349947 -0.13050827
[5,] 0.00000  0.00000000  0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.84370373

$parameters$variance$sigma
, , 1

            V18          V19          V20          V21         V22
V18  1.11483935 -0.046114371  0.021088813  0.094512987 -0.03160755
V19 -0.04611437  0.604042865 -0.001037869  0.001748973  0.13845048
V20  0.02108881 -0.001037869  0.511536706  0.112759387 -0.17223313
V21  0.09451299  0.001748973  0.112759387  0.542454933 -0.13187494
V22 -0.03160755  0.138450479 -0.172233126 -0.131874937  0.81860855




$loglik
[1] -4279.837

attr(,"returnCode")
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

All of these parameters are described in the **Value** section of `mvn` document. You can find in document by typing `?mvn` in R command prompt.

> **Value** (the return value of mvn function)
>
> A list including the following components:
>
> **modelName**
>   A character string identifying the model (same as the input argument).
>
> **parameters**
>
> **mean**
>   The mean for each component. If there is more than one component, this is a >matrix whose kth column is the mean of the kth component of the mixture model.
>
> **variance**
>   A list of variance parameters for the model. The components of this list >depend on the model specification. See the help file for `mclustVariance` for >details.
>
> **loglik** 
>   The log likelihood for the data in the mixture model.
>
> **Attributes:**
>   "WARNING" An appropriate warning if problems are encountered in the >computations.

`mclusVariance` documentation contains more information about `variance` parameters.

Here is the related section of [`mclustVariance` documentation](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/mclust/html/mclustVariance.html).